# Qualitative tests for sodium peroxoborate

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Recently in a chemistry lab I preformed two qualitative tests on sodium peroxoborate.

The procedure for the qualitative tests involved taking a small amount(about 0.2g) dry dry $\ce{Na2[B2(O2)2(OH)4].6H2O}$ and dissolving it in water making up the solution to $10\ \mathrm{mL}$. I then divided it into to small beakers.

1. To one beaker I added 5 drops of 1M sulfuric acid and then add 0.02M $\ce{KMnO4}$ solution dropwise.
2. To the other beaker I added 5 drops of 1M sulfuric acid and then add 10% of potassium iodide solution dropwise.

What are the the balanced equations for these reactions?

Comment: It's possible that they are oxidation reactions but I wouldn't know the actual equation.

Comment: Related: [Qualitative permanganate test on sodium peroxoborate](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9550/7951)